# how to remove page name from url in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

from the following url :

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/default.aspx
```

I want to remove the default.aspx so the url will look like :

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/
```

I need a quick and clean way to do this , and I only need to do this with default.aspx page and no ther pages . thanks in advance .

Comment: `my_url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/"`. Bam! Removed!

Comment: @Karamafrooz, by default your default page can vary it can be default.html or index.html or default.aspx. So if you just want to remove it from URL you have mentioned dont specify page name and default.aspx opens by default and wont be visible in url as well

Comment: Do you want to remove default.aspx when  user requests for this url http://www.mywebsite.com/default.aspx?
If user navigate http://www.mywebsite.com/ directly there will not be default.aspx appended.

Comment: @ Subin Jacob I don't want default.aspx to be showwn on any condition

Comment: @Karamafrooz, what you need is URL rewriting, for how to do that follow link to my response below else make a google search with "url rewriting asp.net" and you have whole bunch of articles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

change your webconfig with below code:it solve my same problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="default.aspx Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*\/)*default\.aspx$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" negate="true" pattern="^POST$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use [Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

in Global.asax file

```
     protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);  
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("defualt",
                            "",
                        "~/Default.aspx");
    }
```

and in your redirection page call

```
Response.Redirect(GetRouteUrl("defualt", null));
```

for more info read :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: What's the point of calling `Response.Redirect(GetRouteUrl("defualt", null));`? The first snippet just works.

Answer (score 1):

By default your default page can vary it can be default.html or index.html or default.aspx depending on the preference. So if you just want to remove it from URL you have mentioned dont specify page name and default.aspx opens by default and wont be visible in url as well

Whereas if you want to do URL rewriting,there are various ways you can do this, you can make changes in web.config or can have a httpModule of your own have a look at below link:-

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2538/URL-Rewriting-with-ASP-NET

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.mywebsite.com/default.aspx");
string urlIWant = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
```

Comment: If you want to remove the name code side you must follow this. Your question isn't clear! @Karamafrooz

Comment: what after urlIWant??, where to place this code and will the above do url rewriting on its own

Comment: If you want a url rewrite this is not the solution for you. If you need the url for some other action - use the code above wherever you need in your code.