# Redirect https secondary domain web-config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dns, iis-7, web-config, redirect

I have one Secondary domain in my host

I want to read  **https : //Mydoaminname.com**

but after add this code For redirect here is my problems address bar :

**https : //Mydoaminname.com/Mydoaminname/**

```
<configuration>

    <system.web>

  <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>

    </system.web>
  <system.webServer>


   <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
      <clear />
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>

    <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\(compressionType)\(AppPool)\(WebSite)\compressed files">
      <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" staticCompressionLevel="9" />
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      </dynamicTypes>
      <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>



    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true"/>




  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

This rewrite code its work great for primary domain but for secondary its make address bar problems

```
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />

                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove page name from url in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399220/how-to-remove-page-name-from-url-in-asp-net)

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI is it one bug , in my code and this si not one default.aspx  can you write the correct codes for me is that good solution your link for seo

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI this code add the Folder name not page names